# Bootstrap Input Group Resize Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to front end development and trying to figure out what my bootstrap input-group keeps doing this when testing for mobile. Any help/advice would be appreciated thanks.

[image: Bootstrap not shrinking]

Here is the html I am using for this.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <form id="Form_UniversitySearch">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="query" name="query" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Search..." style="height: 46px;">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search for University</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should include the CSS you're applying because it doesn't appear to be doing this with the code you posted.

Comment: i'll remember that for next time - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is almost correct.

I have implemented the code here -> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/zj27tfxe/)

html code:

```
<div class="container wrap">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">               
            <form id="Form_UniversitySearch">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="query" name="query" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <a href="#" class="btn personal-button btn-primary btn-lg">Search for University</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

so.. I think should be something wrong in your `css` code.

I hope it's helps.

Note: I have removed the style you have added in the input `style="height: 46px;"` so maybe it was the problem.